# How can I use cordova-plugin-advanced-websocket with Capacitor?

Tags: ionic-framework, websocket, capacitor, capacitor-plugin

How can I use the following cordova plugin in a ionic/capacitor project?
**cordova-plugin-advanced-websocket**

I did:
`npm install cordova-plugin-advanced-websocket`

And then tried the following to access it:

- `CordovaWebsocketPlugin.wsConnect(...)`
  -> I get the error: `Cannot find name 'CordovaWebsocketPlugin'.`
- `window.CordovaWebsocketPlugin.wsConnect(...)`
  -> I get the error: `Property 'CordovaWebsocketPlugin' does not exist on type 'Window & typeof globalThis'.`

I also found the cordova-plugin-advanced-websocket-types plugin : `npm i --save-dev cordova-plugin-advanced-websocket-types`. But I did not get more luck :

```js
import {
  CordovaWebsocketOptions
} from 'cordova-plugin-advanced-websocket-types';
const wsOptions: CordovaWebsocketOptions = {...};
window.CordovaWebsocketPlugin.wsConnect(wsOptions, ...)
```

-> I get the same error: `Property 'CordovaWebsocketPlugin' does not exist on type 'Window & typeof globalThis'.`

I thought about importing this way:
`import { CordovaWebsocketPlugin } from 'cordova-plugin-advanced-websocket/www/plugin'`
-> but I get the error: `Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'cordova/exec' in '...\node_modules\cordova-plugin-advanced-websocket\www'`.
After reading about this I realise that this is not the right way anyway.

---

I need to find a solution to implement secured websocket with self-signed certificates (this is a hard pre-requisite, the security is handled by being on a secured network) on ionic/ios+android+web.
My failed attempt with websocket on iOS have been leading me to use a capacitor/cordova plugin.

I am using the latest version of both ionic and capacitor :
"ionic": "^5.4.16"
"@capacitor/cli": "3.3.1"

Comment: Did you remember to run `npx cap sync` after `npm install`?

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer.
Yes, I have run the `npx cap sync command` (just to be extra sure I re-ran it right now) :
and the plugin seems to be recognized by capacitor :

update android [info] Found 1 Cordova plugin for android:
       cordova-plugin-advanced-websocket@1.1.6

Also, as further information : 
I created a mock project with cordova but I encounter the same problem.

Comment: Try: `declare var CordovaWebsocketPlugin` after all your imports.

Answer (score 0):

Might be stupid but did you try `(window as any).CordovaWebsocketPlugin.wsConnect(...)` ?

For some reason I did this with facebook pixel tracking and it worked for me. Give it a try!

Comment: Hello Callan,

Thank you for answering, unfortunately this does not do the trick as CordovaWebsocketPlugin is not in the window object (I have just tried).

FYI, I did some console.log(window) and it is also not registered in the window.Capacitor.Plugins object.